# If $t$ and $y$ are functions of $x$, and $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-t}\frac{dy}{dt}$, why is the second derivative found as follows?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, chain-rule

If $t=\ln(x)$, $y$ some function of $x$, and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^{-t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, why would the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ be:
$$-e^{-t}\frac{dt}{dx}\frac {dy}{dt} + e^{-t}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}?$$

I know this links into the chain rule. I don't have a good intuition for why the first term has $\dfrac{dt}{dx}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ (although I strongly feel it's such that we can change the variable, since this question arose in the context of a second order differential equation where $y$ was differentiated in terms of $x$, but the equation was non linear, so we had to make it linear by substitution). Moreover, the proper problem that I would plead to be adressed is why the second term is differentiated in the way that it is. Basically, my question is: why is the differential of $\dfrac{dt}{dx}\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ with respect to $x$ given as $\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}\dfrac{dt}{dx}$.

Preferable if english to explain any mathematical derivations, but any of your personal time to help out is always much appreciated.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your math text. This link may be useful as a reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please forgive me. I have an exam in 5 hours, filled with complex numbers, first order, second order differentials, polar coordinates, complex series summations... and a lot more.

Comment: It is often helpful to make a full substitution instead of using the same letters with invisible markers for implied meaning. Thus define $u(t)=y(e^t)$, $y(x)=u(\ln(x))$, so that the application of the chain rule becomes more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your substitution $t=\ln (x) $, the differentiation wrt $x $ is a differentiation wrt $t $ multiplied by $e^{-t} $.
thus

$$\frac {d}{dx}(\frac {dy}{dx})=\frac {d}{dt}(\frac {dy}{dx})e^{-t} $$

$$=\frac {d}{dt}(\frac {dy}{dt}e^{-t})e^{-t} $$

$$=(\frac {d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac {dy}{dt})e^{-2t}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=e^{-t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}\\
\implies\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)&=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-t}\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)\\
\implies\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}&=e^{-t}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)+\dfrac{dy}{dt}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-t}\right)\\
&=e^{-t}\cdot\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}+\dfrac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}\\
&=e^{-t}\cdot\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}-e^{-t}\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}\\
&=-e^{-t}\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{dy}{dt}+e^{-t}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dt}{dx}
\end{align}